# Round minute values in time stamp to next 10th of minutes in pandas data farme

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data farme in `pandas` which has a column called `timestamp`. Contents are below.

```
timestamp
2016-09-01 10:21:00 
2016-09-01 16:52:00 
2016-10-31 18:40:00
```

Now I want to round the `minutes` in the timestamp to `next 10 minutes`

The `expected result` is below

```
timestamp
2016-09-01 10:30:00 
2016-09-01 17:00:00 
2016-10-31 18:50:00
```

For this I have created a function like below

```
def round_datetime(dtime, round_to = 10):
tmp = dtime
mins = tmp.minute
tmp = tmp - timedelta(minutes=mins%round_to)
return tmp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00')
```

I have applied this function to the data frame

```
df['round_dtime'] = df['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: round_datetime(x))
```

The result I am getting is below.

```
timestamp
2016-09-01 10:20:00 
2016-09-01 16:50:00 
2016-10-31 18:40:00
```

What should I do in order to get the desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
print (df['timestamp'].dt.floor('10T') + pd.offsets.DateOffset(minutes=10))
0   2016-09-01 10:30:00
1   2016-09-01 17:00:00
2   2016-10-31 18:50:00
Name: timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: thank you for your answer It works for me. But I would like to know why my function didn't give the results expected.

Comment: Change `tmp = tmp - timedelta(minutes=mins%round_to)` to `tmp = tmp + timedelta(minutes=round_to - mins%round_to)`.

Comment: or better `tmp = tmp - pd.Timedelta(minutes=(mins%round_to - round_to))`